# Move account from one server to another with WHM

Tags: cpanel, whm

I have a question that I hope can be answered and I don't know of any other place to do it so I hope you guys can help.

I have a account that I want to move from my one dedicated server to a new dedicated server. Now I have done this using WHM account transfer, and the domain is showing on the new server. But when I do a ping to the domain, the IP address is still the same as the old server. But after the transfer was complete, it said in WHM that the IP address was updated to the new servers address. Is there something I'm missing or I did wrong?

Please help. I'm a virgin with this (My first time hahaha)

Comment: WHM transfer will create correct A record in zone files but you have to set/edit the name server or at least name server IP to your new server from the domain registrar end. Let me know the domain name so that I can help you further with... Migrating the accounts over WHM is just a piece of cake. Once you did nicely, You don't have to think twice next time :)

Comment: The domain name is www.mytracer.mobi The old server IP is 196.38.40.144 and the new server is 154.0.160.35 I would really appreciate if you could give me some direction with the name server change at the registar on how I do that. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi Leo. That sorted our my problem. Thank you so much for all your help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: You can ping me at my E-mail in case if you need any advise.... :D

Comment: Leo I don't know if you can, but ill really appreciate it if you could thumbs up my question so I can return the favor. I need 1 reputation point more.

Comment: lol... I did. Just note that name server is always taking from the domain registrar end. So you will get a clear idea to resolve such issues next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how your domain mytracer.mobi is resolving right now.

```
mytracer.mobi.          86400   IN      NS      ns.dns2.co.za.
mytracer.mobi.          86400   IN      NS      ns.dns1.co.za.
mytracer.mobi.          86400   IN      NS      ns.otherdns.com.
mytracer.mobi.          86400   IN      NS      ns.otherdns.net.
;; Received 138 bytes from 199.249.126.1#53(b2.mobi.afilias-nst.org) in 18 ms

mytracer.mobi.          7260    IN      A       196.38.40.144
;; Received 47 bytes from 197.242.144.5#53(ns.dns2.co.za) in 272 ms
```

It is using the name servers as shown with NS records and still pointing to your old server IP 196.38.40.144.

So you will have to change/edit the A record with new server IP 154.0.160.35 from your name server end. Thant means A record should change where your name servers are pointing to.

I hope this will resolve your confusion.

Comment: great answer. So basically, assuming all domains are pointing to cpanel NS, all that is needed is to move all the WHM / CPANEL and then just change the A record on WHM ?

Comment: Not exactly Obmerk. NS records are always associated at registrar end. If you have correctly provided the custom NS at registrar end and pointing it to your WHM server, then you are good to make A record changes at WHM DNS zone. OR if you are using stock registrar provided NS and at registrar end, then you will have to change the A record thing at registrar end zone file. Sorry, I can't explain this in less confusing way than this. Hope this helps.